# alsa - arecord generating blank wav file

Tags: audio, alsa

I'm trying to record an audio file via arecord on embeded Linux, but the file is blank. In Audacity, it looks like this:

[image: The audio file's wave]

But I could play ordinary audio file via aplay. I use RK809 as the sound card, which is connected to the cpu via I2S. There is an analog microphone connected to RK809, and the analog audio is processed by RK809 and transmitted to CPU through I2S bus.

Here is some information about it:

```
[root@DCIR:~]# cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [rockchiprk809co]: rockchip_rk809- - rockchip,rk809-codec
                      rockchip,rk809-codec
 7 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1

[root@DCIR:~]# amixer scontrols
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
Simple mixer control 'Playback Path',0
Simple mixer control 'Capture MIC Path',0
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0

[root@DCIR:~]# amixer controls
numid=3,iface=MIXER,name='Master Playback Volume'
numid=2,iface=MIXER,name='Capture MIC Path'
numid=1,iface=MIXER,name='Playback Path'
numid=4,iface=MIXER,name='Digital Capture Volume'

[root@DCIR:~]# amixer scontents
Simple mixer control 'Master',0
  Capabilities: pvolume
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 100
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 100 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Playback 100 [100%] [0.00dB]
Simple mixer control 'Playback Path',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'OFF' 'RCV' 'SPK' 'HP' 'HP_NO_MIC' 'BT' 'SPK_HP' 'RING_SPK' 'RING_HP' 'RING_HP_NO_MIC' 'RING_SPK_HP'
  Item0: 'SPK_HP'
Simple mixer control 'Capture MIC Path',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'MIC OFF' 'Main Mic' 'Hands Free Mic' 'BT Sco Mic'
  Item0: 'Main Mic'
Simple mixer control 'Digital',0
  Capabilities: cvolume
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 100
  Front Left: Capture 100 [100%] [0.00dB]
  Front Right: Capture 100 [100%] [0.00dB]
```

[image: alsamixer]

Here is what I've tried:

1. Record at least 10 seconds to make sure it's not I/O error.
2. Check the hardware. I checked MIC, but it's hard for me to check I2S bus, because to measure the I2S signal, you can only directly measure the pins of the chip.

The following is the method suggested by the chip manufacturer, but I don't know how to implement it:

1. *"Use amixer or tinymix to check if the ADC channel inside the CODEC is open and the volume is muted."* In alsamixer, i'm sure the Capture MIC Path is not off, and Digital is not muted. I don't know how to check ADC's status.
2. *"Codec end input a 10k Hz wave signal which is produced by signal generator."* Is this means send sigal on I2S bus?
3. *"Use arecord or tinycap to record, whether the positioning problem occurs in user mode or kernel mode."* I use command `arecord -D hw:0,0 -d 2 -f cd -c 2 -vv -t wav test.wav`  to record, generating a blank file.

(Update:)

```
[root@DCIR:/]# ls -ails /dev/snd
total 0
 181 0 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root       240 Aug  4 09:00 .
1025 0 drwxr-xr-x 13 root root      4200 Aug  4 09:00 ..
8996 0 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root        80 Aug  4 09:00 by-path
1097 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,   0 Aug  4 09:00 controlC0
 187 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 224 Aug  4 09:00 controlC7
1096 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  24 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC0D0c
1095 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  16 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC0D0p
 184 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 248 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC7D0c
 183 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 240 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC7D0p
 186 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 249 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC7D1c
 185 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116, 241 Aug  4 09:00 pcmC7D1p
 182 0 crw-rw----  1 root audio 116,  33 Aug  4 09:00 timer
```

I used an oscilloscope to measure the SDO/PDMDATA signal of the I2S bus between the sound card (rk809) and the CPU, and found that there is an output signal when recording.

While I use `arecord -Dhw:0,0 -f cd -d 5 -vvv audio.wav`, `dat` format, `-f S16_LE` or `-f S32_LE`, the alsa get volume 0, eg.

```
[root@DCIR:~]# arecord -Dhw:0,0 -f cd -d 5 -vvv audio.wav
Recording WAVE 'audio.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
Hardware PCM card 0 'rockchip,rk809-codec' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S16_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 16
  buffer_size  : 22052
  period_size  : 5513
  period_time  : 125011
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 5513
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 22052
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1445199872
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00000001 #                    0%
```

But when I use `S24_LE`, I got 200% volume:

```
[root@DCIR:~]# arecord -Dhw:0,0 -r 44100 -f S24_LE -c 2 -d 10 -vvv audio.wav
Recording WAVE 'audio.wav' : Signed 24 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo
Hardware PCM card 0 'rockchip,rk809-codec' device 0 subdevice 0
Its setup is:
  stream       : CAPTURE
  access       : RW_INTERLEAVED
  format       : S24_LE
  subformat    : STD
  channels     : 2
  rate         : 44100
  exact rate   : 44100 (44100/1)
  msbits       : 32
  buffer_size  : 22052
  period_size  : 5513
  period_time  : 125011
  tstamp_mode  : NONE
  tstamp_type  : MONOTONIC
  period_step  : 1
  avail_min    : 5513
  period_event : 0
  start_threshold  : 1
  stop_threshold   : 22052
  silence_threshold: 0
  silence_size : 0
  boundary     : 1445199872
  appl_ptr     : 0
  hw_ptr       : 0
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
Max peak (11026 samples): 0x00ffffff #################### 200%
```

Comment: What is your init system ? Please post output of ls -ails /dev/snd

Comment: @MC68020 Hello friend, I'm a novice to audio. What's `init system` means? The driver init function or whatelse?